# Unable to update state variables of inherited contracts

Tags: solidity, tokens, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I'm trying to write an extension of OpenZeppelin's CappedCrowdsale to allow for a hard cap in USD, as I think this is more human-readable than having everything in wei.

However, I'm having issues updating some of the inherited state variables (Crowdsale's `rate` and CappedCrowdsale's `cap`). I try to do this in the `updateEthPrice` function, which I know is getting called because the `ethPriceInDollars` variable gets updated correctly, but **cap** and `rate` always return 1... (which is what they were initialized with)

At first I thought that maybe the inherited constructors were firing after the base constructor (and overriding whatever I set in the base constructor), but even if I call `updateEthPrice` once the contract has been deployed, I'm still not seeing any changes to `cap` and `rate`

Been banging my head on this all day, any help is appreciated!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";


/**
 * @title DollarCappedCrowdsale
 * @author Gianni Settino
 * @dev Extension of CappedCrowdsale with a cap in USD instead of wei.
 * This means that Crowdsale's rate and CappedCrowdsale's cap now depend
 * on ETH's USD price, which can be changed up until the start of the token sale.
 */
contract DollarCappedCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale(1), Ownable {
  uint256 public ethPriceInDollars;
  uint256 public hardCapInDollars;
  uint256 public tokenPriceInCents;

  // @dev We temporarily init Crowdsale's rate and CappedCrowdsale's cap to 1.
  // Reason: their "real" values are subsequently calculated in updateEthPrice()
  function DollarCappedCrowdsale(
    uint256 _startTime,
    uint256 _endTime,
    address _wallet,
    uint256 _ethPriceInDollars,
    uint256 _hardCapInDollars,
    uint256 _tokenPriceInCents
    )
    public
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, 1, _wallet)
  {
    require(_hardCapInDollars > 0);
    require(_tokenPriceInCents > 0);
    hardCapInDollars = _hardCapInDollars;
    tokenPriceInCents = _tokenPriceInCents;
    updateEthPrice(_ethPriceInDollars);
  }

  function updateEthPrice(uint256 _ethPriceInDollars) public onlyOwner {
    require(now < startTime);
    require(_ethPriceInDollars > 0);
    ethPriceInDollars = _ethPriceInDollars;
    cap = (hardCapInDollars / ethPriceInDollars).mul(1 ether);
    rate = (ethPriceInDollars.mul(100)) / tokenPriceInCents;
  }
}
```

Comment: What values are you using for the constructor parameters? The only suspicious code is `cap = (hardCapInDollars / ethPriceInDollars).mul(1 ether)`, depending on the values the division will truncate and loss presicion, a alternative is to first multiply `cap = hardCapInDollars.mul(1 ether) / ethPriceInDollars`.

Comment: `DollarCappedCrowdsale(START_TIME, START_TIME.add(LENGTH_IN_SEC), msg.sender, _ethPriceInDollars, HARD_CAP_IN_DOLLARS, TOKEN_PRICE_IN_CENTS)`

where START_TIME = 1519603200, LENGTH_IN_SEC = 7 days, _ethPriceInDollars = 870 (passed when we deploy the contract), HARD_CAP_IN_DOLLARS = 40000000, and TOKEN_PRICE_IN_CENTS = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your contractin remix and it works as expected. The modified version to be used with latest version of OpenZeppelin contracts.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";

contract DollarCappedCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale(1), Ownable {
  uint256 public ethPriceInDollars;
  uint256 public hardCapInDollars;
  uint256 public tokenPriceInCents;

  function DollarCappedCrowdsale(
    uint256 _startTime,
    uint256 _endTime,
    address _wallet,
    uint256 _ethPriceInDollars,
    uint256 _hardCapInDollars,
    uint256 _tokenPriceInCents
    )
    public
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, 1, _wallet, MintableToken(1))
  {
    require(_hardCapInDollars > 0);
    require(_tokenPriceInCents > 0);
    hardCapInDollars = _hardCapInDollars;
    tokenPriceInCents = _tokenPriceInCents;
    updateEthPrice(_ethPriceInDollars);
  }

  function updateEthPrice(uint256 _ethPriceInDollars) public onlyOwner {
    require(now < startTime);
    require(_ethPriceInDollars > 0);
    ethPriceInDollars = _ethPriceInDollars;
    cap = (hardCapInDollars / ethPriceInDollars).mul(1 ether);
    rate = (ethPriceInDollars.mul(100)) / tokenPriceInCents;
  }
}
```

Creation parameters

```
1518412209,1518413209,"0x01","870","40000000","10"
```

Resulting parameters:

- rate: 8700
- tokenPriceInCents: 10
- hardCapInDollars: 40000000
- ethPriceInDollars: 870
- cap: 45977000000000000000000

Comment: Amazing, this works, thank you so much! I had to start using the new version of OpenZeppelin's Crowdsale contract, I'll do a deep dive and see what changed to make it work all of a sudden...

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, you're inheriting the CappedCrowdsale Contract incorrectly. See the answer below and let me know how that works out.

```
contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {

    function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, MintableToken _token) public
        CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
        FinalizableCrowdsale()
        RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
        Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet, _token)
    {
    //As goal needs to be met for a successful crowdsale
    //the value needs to less or equal than a cap which is limit for accepted funds
        require(_goal <= _cap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I would suggest using SafeMath for ALL of your math functions.

Comment: Hi Dorian, thanks for your response. I’m actually trying to update the inherited **cap** and **rate** state variables, not the ones from DollarCappedCrowdsale. As for SafeMath, I noticed that for division, it doesn’t make a difference (ie SafeMath isn’t doing any assertions), and the syntax is cleaner using the / operator. Is this against best practices? Cheers!

Comment: Is the inheritance of CappedCrowdsale(1) the correct way? I only use 'is BasicToken', for instance... Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Oh yeah, ok I see. Just don't use CappedCrowdsale(1) and use CappedCrowdsale. Then in the CappedCrowdsale set the variable to 1. uint256 cap = 1; then just update as necessary. I have found it difficult to construct other contracts using variables so I just initialize them with the hardcoded variable, then use functions to change them

Comment: That seems... bad. Don’t think it’s good practice to go into an OpenZeppelin contract and start modifying the code... And ya, CappedCrowdsale(1) is the proper way of inheriting from CappedCrowdsale with a constructor parameter of 1 (you can also do this in the DollarCappedCrowdsale constructor like you would for a modifier)

Comment: I updated my answer. but I have to ask why you think it is bad practice to modify code? So if I wanted to add a function to the contract, I should just not? lol

Comment: Also, technically you've already modified the contract by inheriting incorrectly as per their instructions. So I'm taking your comment as a joke! lol

Comment: If you wanted to add a function to the contract, you would extend it and add the function there. It's **terrible** practice to be editing OpenZeppelin's code, as it's been audited, bulletproofed, and used for hundreds of crowdsales. The only correct way to use the library is to install zeppelin-solidity via NPM and then import the desired code and inherit from it.

Comment: As for inheriting incorrectly, CappedCrowdsale(1) is totally fine, according to this: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors

"The first way to do it is more convenient if the constructor argument is a constant"